# Looking for an alternative way to filter my objects before using a django-filters class

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I've implemented a filter using the django-filters third party framework but want to run the filter on an already filtered set which was giving errors.

```py
class BlogView(ListView):
    template_name="blog/blog.html"
    model = Post

#    def get_queryset(self):
#        return Post.objects.filter(posted_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by("-posted_date")[:25]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['filter'] = PostFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
      return context
```

my view ^ my filter v

```py
class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["title"]
```

My blog needs the ability to schedule posts in the future meaning when i display them i am filtering posts by `posted_date__lte=timezone.now()`

however this is causing a problem when i am then using the filter because i cannot filter an already spliced object. I've read through and understand the problem comes from the way the database works so i am looking for an alternative way to make only posts that `posted_date__lte=timezone.now()` show without using the currently commented out `def get_queryset` filter i was previously using.

edit* maybe in the line:
`context['filter'] = PostFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=SOMETHINGHERE())` i can add the filter to SOMETHINGHERE in some way?

Comment: Why you don't just remove `[:25]` from your queryset? This is what is giving you the trouble. Use pagination or splice your request after whole filtering is done.

Comment: Thanks! this solved it and now i feel like an idiot. I did not even consider the error was simply coming from there at all